# Why we add acceleration of celestial body with acceleration of spaceship to determine force exerted by space ship on astronaut?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

The acceleration due to gravity acts in the downward direction, and a spaceship accelerates in an upward direction. Therefore, why do we add the accelerations together instead of subtracting them?

Comment: Remained part of question is determine the magnitude of force exerted by the spaceship on astronaut

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: Actually my doubt is about concept not formulae but I will try to use Mathjax

Comment: You also shouldn't post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines and screen readers.

Comment: I am new but now always keep it in my mind

Answer (score 1):

Think of being in an elevator, as it accelerates upward you feel heavier, this is adding Earth's gravity plus upward acceleration. When the elevator accelerates downward you feel lighter, this is subtracting downward acceleration from Earth's gravity.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that in your scenerio, the astronaut is taking off from a planet and you are trying to find the net g-force experienced by the astronaut. One thing that you have to understand is that there are some differences between the acceleration due to gravity and the acceleration of the spaceship( though they are fundementally same as per relativity) from an astraunut perspective.

Acceleration due to gravity: The planet is pulling on the astronut. If the astronut is not held at rest by some other force, he will be in free fall and he wont experience any g-force. But when your feet touches the earth, earth applies a force equal to gravitational force to keep you at rest relative to the earth. This is the force that you experience as g-force.

Acceleration of space craft: The space craft is accelerating due to the combustion of the fuel, you will be at rest untill you come in contact with rear of the space craft (seat in a real case). Here space craft appiles a force on you and imparts an acceleration 'a'. This is the force that keeps you at rest on the space craft frame, and thus be counted as g-force.

The above mentioned forces are the real forces that can be attributed to g-force. Acctual g-force is pseudo and is opposite in direction to these. Now i think you can safely add g and a.

Answer (score 0):

It's common sense when you think about it. When the space ship, Apollo let's say, is standing on the launch pad, the astronauts feel a force of 1g pressing them into their seats. When the launch takes place, this 1g force doesn't vanish, but continues to act on the astronauts. As the rocket gradually rises into the air and accelerates, the astronauts are subjected to additional g forces, just as you would be if you sat in the seat of a high performance sports car going from 0 to 60mph in a few seconds. After a short while, the astronauts are being subjected to an acceleration of about 8g, but that doesn't last very long (it would be very bad for their health if it did). It's only when the rocket motors are shut down and the rocket coasting in a parabola that weightlessness sets in. At that stage it is in effect falling back to Earth, but as fast as it falls back the Earth beneath them curves away, so they never get any closer. They are then in orbit, and in a state of free fall.